# getting an error from api fatch request - Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node.js and I'm trying to making an api But when i try to do a fatch request from a different url i get an error But if i do a fatch request from the same url it works fine.

The error i get: `Error: Failed to fetch`

My index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const LimitingMiddleware = require('limiting-middleware');
const app = express();

app.use(new LimitingMiddleware().limitByIp());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use('/facts', require('./routes/facts'));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html");
});

app.get('/ping', (req, res) => {
  res.send('pong');
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;

  res.status(statusCode).json({
    type: 'error', message: err.message
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Server Start at 3000 Port`));
```

The routes/facts.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { randomFact } = require('../fact-handler');

router.get('/random', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ api_test: 'Works' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a relative URL to the `fetch()` method when making a request, instead of absolute URL, i.e. instead of `fetch('http://localhost:3000/facts/random')`, use `fetch('/facts/random')`, so it will resolve to the host serving the file, allowing you to run it on multiple environments.

Try serving this as `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    // use relative URL to run on any environement
    // forward slash indicates that the path is relative to the domain root
    fetch('/facts/random', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    }).then((response) => {
        // parse JSON response into native JavaScript objects
        // return for processing
        return response.json();
    }).then((response) => {
        // success
        console.log('it works', response);
        document.write(JSON.stringify(response));
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });;

});
</script>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```